# To what depth can a new algorithm be presented while applying for PhD?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, application

I am applying for PhD to German and Finnish universities.

I do not have any publication  date. Hence there is no direct proof that I can do the research.

However I am working on an algorithm. The work is more than 60% complete. I have a confidence that method will be accepted for publication as it is in a lower quality journal, but there exists a belief that if I push a little harder, it will be a material for a very good publication, signifying original work.

Hence, I am thinking of sending the work done up till now with the application, but I have the following  concerns.

1. What if people there take my work, modify it, and publish it? I have a feeling that I will be helpless even if someone publishes it as it is.
2. I am working alone on this project. Will my work have any importance? Because around 98% of the papers I have read were from multiple authors, belonging to some academic entity.
3. Is there any alternative in making person next to me believe that I can do the research, other than publication? Even though our (professor's and mine) area of interest is the same, we are targeting the problem from two different ends, and I obviously do not have time to study his entire work.

Your answer is going to be a key factor in my deciding my approach.

Comment: _method will be accepted as publication as it is in less quality journal_ I do not understand what you mean here. Are there peer-reviewed journals which will accept  algorithm only publication?

Comment: First of all, you are talking about publishing an algorithm and in CS experimental algorithms  are usually published in conferences and not journals. Also, a publication in a mediocre-to-bad journal will not benefit you. Third, submitting something that is 60% ready will probably lead to rejection. Why can't you complete the work before submitting?

Comment: @scaaahu I meant to say that, the work done till now, can be published today, as it is, without any further additions. But that will not be IEEE Transaction paper kind of thing..

Comment: @Alexandros, thank you. I agree with quality of a publication. Work is 60% ready, because there are few blockages, I need a guidance to complete it, which is not available in my proximity. This is one of the reasons of doing the PhD.

Comment: Do you have a Master's degree? Did that not require some research?